# Rails helper method to display email with sub mask asterisk

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, actionviewhelper

How to write like a helper method for email address to display with sub mask asterisk.

If user email address is like "john.a@stackoverflow.com", But in view I want to display joh***@***.com

```
<%= sub_masked_email("john.a@stackoverflow.com") %>
##joh***@***.com
```

Comment: Did you find an answer? I am struggling with this problem too

Comment: Did you solve this and how?

Answer (score 3):

So you can write a helper method which can be reused multiple time by calling it on any string. Here is what I came up with below:

**helper_method**

```
def sub_masked_email(string)
  string.gsub(/(?<=.{2}).*@.*(?=\S{2})/, '****@****')
end
```

**calling it on any string**

```
sub_masked_email("john.a@stackoverflow.com")
```

**output**

```
"jo*****@****om"
```

So this method shows the first two letters and shows the last two letters and replaces all other text with `****@****`

Just a pointer to what you need and can still be better than this.